# Angular 2 ngFor with Dynamic Data

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items $index"(click)="open($event, item)">
        {{item.Name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>




<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"(click)="open($event, item)">
        {{item[searchKey]}}
</ion-item>
```

how to access json key Dynamically {{item.Name}} &  {{item[searchKey]}}. searchKey  Variable

Comment: `{{item[variable]}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"(click)="open($event, item)">
        {{getListItem(item)}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

getListItem(item) {
  let retItem =''
  for (var prop in item){
      if(prop=this.searchKey)  {
      retItem =item[prop];
     }

    return retItem;
}
```

For Reusable selection component - works Fine